# WCF service reference cannot be added

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, webforms

I created WCF Self Hosted service, i hosted it in C# console application and there it is running perfectly but problems are that when i put localhost URL in browser then it doesn't browse + i cannot add it's reference to Webforms client application, it throws error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8084/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8084
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8084/'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8084/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8084
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

i am running hosting in separate instance of VS 2013 and Client in another as an admin but it doesn't work , why ?

CODE:

Hosting Application:

```
namespace HellloServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(HellloService.HelloService)))
            {
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started @"+ System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="HellloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="MexBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HellloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HellloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8084/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8085/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors >
        <behavior name="MexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

your config file suggests the service address to be:

```
http://localhost:8084/HelloService
```

try that URL to get the service reference. if it still doesn't work, try printing the endpoint address when the service starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I host a service in the console, I dump all the endpoint addresses of the ServiceHost to the console after the sh.Open() method:

```
foreach (var endpoint in sh.Description.Endpoints)
{
  Console.WriteLine(endpoint.Address.Uri);
}
```

This works for endpoints configured via .config file or if you created them in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this endpoint in your configuration (App.config)

```
<endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to start the WCF service in Visual Studio, then select "Detach All" from the Debug menu. This should let the service continue to run in the background, yet open Visual Studio to let you add service references.